# Bijection between $P(A×B)$ and $(P(B))^A$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Define a function from $P(A×B)$ to $(P(B))^A$ and its inverse.

- $P(A)$ is the powerset of $A.$
- $A\times B$ is the cartesian product of set $A$ and set $B.$
- $(P(B))^A$ is the set of functions from set $A$ to powerset of set $B.$

The question is posted as it was asked. There was genuinely no other context and I've included my own thoughts below. This is not homework but I'm preparing for examinations for undergraduate computer science discrete math module and need some help.

Let $x \in X, y \in Y, X \subseteq A, Y \subseteq B$

For the forward function:
$f(X \times Y) (x) \rightarrow \{y|(x,y) \in X \times Y\}$

How do you get the reverse?

$f^{-1}(g(x,Y)) = \{(x,y)|y\in Y\}$ seems to return $a \times B$ rather than $A \times B$.

Comment: Your question would benefit from added [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). It would also help if you defined P(AxB) and [A ⇒ P(B)] - it is not immediately clear to me what you mean by these.

Comment: The question makes more sense now, thanks! However, I do not understand the function  $f$ you are trying to define. This needs to take as input a set of subsets of $X\times Y$, i.e. $S\subset P(X\times Y)$, but you have only defined it for elements $x\in X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define
$$F:P(A×B)\to(P(B))^A$$
by: for every subset $X$ of $A×B,$ $F(X)$ is the map defined on $A$ by
$$\forall a\in A\quad F(X)(a)=
\{b\in B\mid(a,b)\in X\}.$$
Define
$$G:(P(B))^A\to P(A×B)$$
by: for every map $f:A\to P(B),$
$$G(f)=\{(a,b)\mid a\in A,\;b\in f(a)\}.$$
You can check that
$$G(F(X))=X\text{ and }F(G(f))=f$$
for every such $X$ and $f.$ This proves that $F$ is a bijection and $G=F^{-1}.$

Comment: The question has been rewritten and reopened but the downvoters forgot to revise their opinion. I anwered it despite its negative score because it is a standard and useful question but I found no duplicate.